# Issue with pie chart matplotlib - startangle / len()

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I have a script which creates a pie chart based on CSV files. My problem started when I was reading a CSV that had only one row (e.g. `percent = [100]`). Is there any limitation of using a pie chart, where is will not show 100% for only one item? It seems that the error is related to either the `startangle` or `explode` arguments.

My code is:

```
percent = [100]

plt.pie(percent,        # data
    explode=(0),        # offset parameters 
    #labels=country,    # slice labels - removed to hid labels and added labels=country in legend()
    colors=colors,      # array of colours
    autopct='%1.0f%%',  # print the values inside the wedges - add % to the values 
    shadow=False,       # enable shadow
    startangle=70       # starting angle
)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.legend(loc='best', labels=country) 
plt.tight_layout()
```

Error in the line of startangle=70:

```
if len(x) != len(explode):
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `explode` parameter to a `list`:

```
percent = [100]
explode = [0]

plt.pie(percent, explode=explode, ...)
```

If you have more values, you can use a `tuple`, but with one value `(int)` is seen as an integer:

```
>>> type((0))
<type 'int'>
>>> type((0, 1))
<type 'tuple'>

>>> type([0])
<type 'list'>
```